# How to set pageSize when using GetByReference in Rally C# API

Tags: c#, rally

**What I want to do:**

I wish to query the Rally API to get all the revisions in a particular userStories history.

Here is my code so far

```
var queryReference = baseURL + $"slm/webservice/v2.0/revisionhistory/{revisionHistoryId}/Revisions";

    DynamicJsonObject myResults = api.GetByReference(queryReference);
```

Which 'works'.

**My Problem:**

the above method seems to have a hard page limit of 20, however the items I'm calling have in excess of 100 revisions.

My Question:

How do I pass the pagesize through using this method?

I've tried this:

`var queryReference = baseURL + $"slm/webservice/v2.0/revisionhistory/{revisionHistoryId}/Revisions?pagesize=200";`

but the queryString parameter is ignored.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting- I'm surprised that the GetByReference is working at all for you.  That method is generally designed for reading a single object, not for querying many.

In order to query that collection you'll want to first use GetByReference to read the RevisionHistory object, fetching Revisions.  Then you can create a new Request, passing the Revisions from the first response to its constructor.  At that point you can set all the normal request parameters.

Does that make sense?